# Cant access CSS or JS files from my Centos 7 apache instance

Tags: html, centos7, php-7

I am using php 7 with the above setup, I gave included in my html the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme.css" type="text/css"> </head>
```

The files can not be accessed directly or through the page, then trying to access them directly I get

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /theme.css on this server.

Any ideas. If this is a 'non programming' question then tell me where I need to ask it. I'm pulling hair out.

Comment: Further to this I have added 777 permission using chmod I know its not the done thing but its a dev machine so isnt important from a security POV

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your urls are correct. i.e. the css files are actually located in the webroot
2. Check permissions: https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: I checked the permissions, even assigned them using chmod with the dreaded 777 on /var/www/html (its a developer machine) I then restarted httpd service but no joy. Still the same error message